# Why is the rxjs pipe function in my httpclient returning Observable<Response | myClass>

Tags: angular, rxjs, httpclient

In this code

```js
getHero(id: number): Observable<Hero> {
  const url = `${this.heroesUrl}/${id}`;
  return this.http.get<Hero>(url).pipe(
    tap(_ => this.log(`fetched hero id=${id}`)),
    catchError(this.handleError<Hero>(`getHero id=${id}`))
  );
}
```

from the Angular documentation [here](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6)
working fine, whereas in my project, "identical" code is giving me the error

> error TS2322: Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.

after upgrading to angular 6?

```js
public getCustomer(customerRecId: string): Observable<Customer> {
  const url = `${this.baseUrl}/Customer?recId=${customerRecId}`;
  const customer$ = this.http.get(url, this.httpOptions).pipe(
    map(this.mapCustomer), 
    catchError(this.handleError)
  );

  return customer$;
}
```

Hovering over the '.pipe' in vsCode shows in the former example it is returning an Observable but in the latter an Observable

I don't understand why the two examples differ.

Comment: The examples don't look the same, to me. One difference is that you are passing unbound methods to the operators and if said methods rely upon  `this`, you will have a problem. In any case, the `Response` part of the union likely comes from the `catchError` operator. The inferred `Response | Hero` type is saying that the `map` operator will emit a `Hero` but the `catchError` operator will emit a `Response`. For your question to be answered precisely, you should include the `catchError` implementation.

Comment: Check your import Observable as there is multiple lib

Comment: Thanks cartant - you pointed me in the right direction! It was, indeed, the catchError that was causing my issue!